# Should we store debug information in application's database

Tags: java, debugging, database-design, logging

We have some service running on 'n' number of hosts behind a VIP. When there is some fault that occurs with specific request call, we might be interested to know the reason by looking at the logs on the respected host where the fault occurred. since the request could go to any host, when it comes to tracking logs, we need to know from which host the fault originated.

One solution is to store the host name in the database of our service along with other information. 
The alternative is, pushing the logs onto a common store and tracing it there.

I personally feel that if we go with the first approach, we might end up in adding many such debugging related attributes in the application database thereby polluting it. However the second option is also not that easy to implement and incurs some overhead. Moreover on which host the fault occurred does not help much except in case the fault occurred due to some hardware specific issue.

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your infrastructure, it's hard to be precise, but here are some general points of view.

I don't like using databases for storing application logs - if the database falls over, you wouldn't be able to log it! It's also not really relational data, and you can't get the monitoring tools that are available for other solutions.

My recommendation is to use your operating system's built in event logging solution; most logging frameworks support this out of the box. On Windows, that's the event log; on *nix there's the syslog system. Logging should be quick, cheap, and bullet proof - that's what you get from the OS tools.

The second question is then how you use those logs for trouble shooting and monitoring. There are lots of tools for doing this, though mostly aimed at system administrators rather than developers. Microsoft have MoM, there's Tivoli and Big Brother - as well as a whole bunch of open source tools. I'd use those, rather than build your own solution.

The key point is - logging should be fast, cheap and robust; the analysis and monitoring stuff should be entirel separate from your application logic, so you can reuse the tools and processes acros multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

storing the hostname should be quite cheap I guess. I understand you are appending logs to a db? 
you could also store the pid for each process, that can help you in case you have multiple processes running on same hostname. The combination hostname/pid/timestamp will ensure you identify uniquely a process.

Comment: This is exactly i'm trying to avoid, we might need more debug information to be stored in database which is not useful for the application per se, but only for the developers.